# How to use an object method (with $this) as a callback in array_filter?

Tags: php, array-filter

I have a public method defined for class `A`:

```
class A{
  public function isValid()
  {
    return $this->getValue==1;
  }
}
```

I want to filter an array of object `A`s using the method defined in class `A`:

```
class B{
  //$input is an array of A objects
  public static function getArray($input)
  {
    return array_filter($input, array($this, “isValid”))
  }
}
```

However, actually `$this` is not valid in class `B`.  How should I input the callback function in the `array_filter` to make it work?

Comment: `return array_filter($input, array("A", “isValid”));` ??

Comment: If I do so, should `isValid` be a static function?

Comment: If it will always be used statically and not as part of an object then yes.

Comment: Got, thanks! @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function that calls `isValid()`

```
return array_filter($input, function($x) { return $x->isValid(); });
```